# How to get into container using GUI tool (like Kitematic) in Docker?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, docker, containers

I have a container that is running the Mozilla Firefox and Chrome service in the foreground. I would like to be able to access the container from UI shell in order to "poke around" inside it and examine the files. At the moment, if I attach to the container.

I know that using `docker exec -it [container-id] bash` command we can get into container through command line but I wanted to access container through UI,So Are there any tools available which can monitor and show what inside container are running ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't seen a good GUI for poking around inside docker containers, but there are constantly new developments. As Docker container process lists are not hidden on the host, you can use  `pstree -cpa` on the host to get all the hosts and all the containers' processes.  This is displayed in tree format, enabling you to determine that certain processes were spawned by docker.